# $maxdistance no longer works when upgrading to MongoDB 2.6.3

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a query on MongoDB which queries for devices located within a certain distance of a location. It's been working perfectly fine for months now. **When I upgraded from MongoDB 2.4.10 to 2.6.3, the query no longer works** and it returns no results.

```
{
    "lastLocation": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ -122.195 , 37.423]
            }
        },
        "$maxDistance": 10000
    }
}
```

After playing around with it, it seems that without $maxDistance, the query works. However, I can't get $maxDistance to work at all.

I have two databases side by side with the exact same data, one with each version of MongoDB, 2.4 returns data, 2.6 does not (so it's not because there aren't devices within that distance).

Is there a known issue with maxDistance, or was there a change in units or how it works?

Index is as follows:

```
{
    v: 1,
    name: "lastLocation_2dsphere",
    key: {
        lastLocation: "2dsphere"
    },
    ns: "s-dev.devices",
    background: true,
    safe: true
}
```

Sample entry:

```
"lastLocation": [-122.19888, 37.42316]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there have been a few changes in 2.6, kind of hidden in the documentation. In your case, in version 2.6 the $maxDistance needs to be inside of the $near document, not outside:

> **$maxDistance Changes¶**
>
> Description
>
> - For $near queries on GeoJSON data, if the queries specify a       $maxDistance, $maxDistance must be inside of the $near document. In
>     previous version, $maxDistance could be either inside or outside the
>     $near document.
> - $maxDistance must be a positive value.
>
> Solution
>
> - Update any existing $near queries on GeoJSON data that currently have    the $maxDistance outside the $near document
> - Update any existing queries where $maxDistance is a negative value.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/

So in your case the query needs to look like this:

```
{
    "lastLocation": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ -122.195 , 37.423]
            },
           "$maxDistance": 10000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed it when looking through the release notes. I guess $maxDistance does make more sense in there, though it's a pity having to go and change the queries everywhere they are used.